# Any way of computing the number of co-prime numbers to $n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, coprime

For a certain problem, I need to compute
$$|\phi(n)|=|\{x\in\mathbb{N} : 0<x<n, gcd(x,n)=1\}|.$$
Is there any "formula" that works for any natural number $n$? Or is it just impossible. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you talking about this function https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function ?

Comment: How large is your $n$? You can compute $\phi(n)$ if you can factor $n$.

Comment: @vvgiri I don't have a determined $n$, I'm looking for a general solution to it. Good to know that it can be known if I can factor $n$.

Comment: If you know the prime factorization of $n$, there is a formula for $\phi(n)$ which you can get in the Wikipedia entry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Euler Totient function:

$$\phi(n) = n \prod_{p | n} \bigg( 1 - {1 \over p} \bigg)$$

counts the positive integers up to a given integer $n$ that are relatively prime to $n$